# can not change a css class value using recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, less

I am using recaptcha for a form and am trying to change its width but not to give.

I have an id that has width 153px! Important and I want to change to 260px but whenever I try the initial value is prevailing.

I already tried these ways:

1st - `$ ('# recaptcha_area') css ({'width': '260px important! '});`

2nd - `$ ('# recaptcha_area') addClass ('test');`

thank you all

Comment: but the input have 153px and i want change to 260px, not 300px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't change as if the minimum width of recaptcha is 300px set by google. But if you want to try you do like this:

```
$('#recaptcha_area').css('width','260px','important');
```

I was also facing this problem later I used `zoom` to decrease it's width. So you can use css like this:

```
#recaptcha_widget_div{zoom: .8}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Jquery confused at the time two important for the same id. Remove the
>   line width:153px !important in css and write simply width : 153px; And
>   then try this

```
$('#recaptcha_area') css({'width': '260px important!'});
```

> Note :    If the same property is declared in both rules, the conflict
>   is  resolved first through specificity, then according to the order of
>   the  CSS declarations. The order of classes in the class attribute is
>   not  relevant.

Comment: setting width of recaptcha is almost impossible I've tried earlier much and then only done with zoom. Is there anyway if you know the better way.